# mod rewrite from .domain to www.domain htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I extend htaccess file to do .domain.com -> www.domain.com?

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        #catch potential subpages first
        RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
        #catch parent page without subpage
        RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
  </IfModule>
```

Is it possible to not define domain.com? and have generic rule for any domain?

Normally I would do like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But how do I unite it with directives above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# anything.com to www.anything.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+(\.[^.]+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

#catch potential subpages first
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

#catch parent page without subpage
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**PS:** If you want to add `www` for subdomains also then use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Edited to make it work on localhost also and yes didn't change any other rule.