# Redirect domain.com/shop to www.domain.com/shop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

Note: Before you mark it duplicate, please read the complete question.
I already applied bellow suggestion which didn't work for me.

1 - [mod rewrite from .domain to www.domain htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097061/mod-rewrite-from-domain-to-www-domain-htaccess)

2 - [.htaccess redirect from http://www.domain/ to https://domain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357592/htaccess-redirect-from-http-www-domain-to-https-domain-com)

3 - [.htaccess redirect any domain/directory to www.domain/directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147098/htaccess-redirect-any-domain-directory-to-www-domain-directory)

We've got a shopping site which we're hosting on a host (CloudLogin). 
The main site is built on Joomla CMS and Magento as shopping cart.

The main site URL is www.domain.com and shopping cart URL is domain.com/shop (Without www).

What we need is to show both URLs with (www).

So we need the Magento folder ie domain.com/shop also to be on www URL.

I found some solutions on stack overflow but they didn't work for me as it always show a message browser (Too many redirection or /page isn't redirecting properly)

**Note:** The .htaccess file is located in (shop) folder.

Bellow is what I tried so far:

1 -

```
# anything.com to www.anything.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+(\.[^.]+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

The above code removes the (shop) directory from URL which turns into error.

ex: domain.com/**shop**/cat1/prod1 turns into www.domain.com/cat1/prod1

2 -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Above code not even apply www on it.

3 -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Above code redirects from domain.com/shop/**cat1**/**prod1** to www.domain.com/shop with error message (redirected you too many times.)
Which seems infinite loop on page.

4 -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/shop/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This does the same thing as 3.

5 -

```
#RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} doamin.com [OR]
#RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} www.doamin.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.doamin.com/shop/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Does anyone know how I can always force the correct use of .htaccess for particular URLs?

I've had a look around SO but couldn't find a suitable answer to this.

Comment: This is what I used `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
RewriteCond www.%{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(www\..+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1/shop%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: It's not redirecting to www :(

Comment: Also tried with (http) instead of (https) if it counts.

Comment: @ZafarS this works fine for me, If i enter http://example.com/foo it gets redirected to http://www.example.com/shop/foo without any problem. may be I misunderstood your requirement.?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
# anything.com to www.anything.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+(\.[^.]+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/shop/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Since requests originate from the `/shop` directory they will not contain that directory in the URL requested.

Comment: Actually it contains, because the URL is set in admin dashboard for this as (/shop)  and I can't change it for some reason.